# AVPlayer is in the ReadyToPlay status but unable to start a playback

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset, avurlasset

Here is my code to start the video:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let playerAV = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
let playerLayerAV = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerAV)
playerLayerAV.frame = ...
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayerAV)
playerAV.play()
```

I can see the video preview, I can also see it's being loaded, I can even move the slider and see that preview is changing to the time I'm choosing. But if I hit play - nothing happens. I tried to press "play" button manually, I tried to call `.play` programmatically, the state of the "Play" button changes to "||" but then switches back to ">" right away.

I'm also tracking debug info related to the player state and I notice the following. Right when I created a player the status is below:

```
Status: ReadyToPlay
TimeControl: WaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate
ReasonToWait: AVPlayerWaitingToMinimizeStallsReason
Time: {0/1 = 0.000}
Rate: 1
Loaded Time Ranges: [Location=0,Length=0]
```

And it almost instantly changes its TimeControl: Paused and Rate: 0:

```
Status: ReadyToPlay
TimeControl: Paused
ReasonToWait:
Time: {0/1 = 0.000}
Rate: 0
Loaded Time Ranges: [Location=0,Length=0]
```

In both cases, it shows that `playerItem.LoadedTimeRanges` has one element but length and locations are 0 when the UI shows that the video has been completely loaded and ready to play.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that there is no issue with the video, views or controllers setup. The video is loaded and ready to play and paused right away because of a mode of the share `audioSession`. It was previously set to `.record` to process another app use-case.

The solution is to restore an original `audioSession` mode which includes playback and the video will play without any issues.